# Contact Form 7 WP PLugin Shows Error when Info is submitted in form. The error is not present when Civi CRM is disabled

Tags: wordpress, civicrm-home

We have been using Contact Form 7 (wordpress plugin) on our page for years to take in responses from our listeners during our live radio show. Recently I am troubleshooting an issue involving the plugin and am hoping someone can help shine light on the cause.

WordPress Version:4.8.1
CiviCRM Version:4.7.17

Description of Issue:
The form shows up correctly though it shows the error message below once you submit the info. The submitted info then makes its way to a specified email address which seems to be working correctly. There may be some emails that are not making it through as per some emails from our listeners.

Troubleshoot:
I disabled all plugins and found that our Civi CRM plugin seems to be contributing to the issue. I have checked the base url and all seems defined correctly.

Other Factors: We did recently switch to SSL though all urls seem correct.

Error Message”
“Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
We can’t load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be enabled in your browser settings. Please check this setting and enable cookies (if they are not enabled). Then try again. If this error persists, contact the site administrator for assistance.Site Administrators: This error may indicate that users are accessing this page using a domain or URL other than the configured Base URL. Error type: Could not find a valid session key.”

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is really digging back into the cobwebs for me but... I had a very similar problem that I think popped up when we set up SSL. I think that in the Form settings, under the Mail tab, I had to remove the To & From mail-tag and just use my actual email address. I may have ended up deleting the current form and creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work! I ended up switching to Ninja forms though a few of our other sites will be switching to SSL and its good to know I can keep Contact Form 7 in use.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use caldera form? I think caldera form familiar because It can send result directly to CiviCRM.